# Which DB for storing geolocation (coordinates) for many users and checking if they are close to each other in real time?

Tags: database, node.js, geolocation, nosql, relational-database

IOS app will send from time to time coordinates to server through REST api. On server inside DB registered users are stored with their coordinates. Each user may have many friends which he want to track if they are close to him. So server after each coordinate update (from user) has to check if his friends are close to him (with a radius also stored in DB per user). It has to handle MANY users.

So many writes to DB all the time and after each write there is computation of friends that are nearby.

As a server technology I would like to use node.js, but I am wondering about which (or what type od DB) use? Are there any databases which will help with all geolocation calculations or are specialy "tweaked" for such computation?

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has [geospatial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) indexes and is pretty common in the node.js world. It has a few query types that are useful when working with geo data.

Comment: I checked it and it seems that this is what I was looking for. But I am wondering if MongoDB (NOSQL) will be the right choice for this app. Maybe some Relational DB which geospacial indexes/operations would be better?

Comment: @user606521 As usual: If unsure, test multiple approaches with some code and go for, what fits best.